# Creating custom fields for a Jira plugin

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I recently started learning to develop plugins for jira. Now I need to create custom fields. I don't know how to name this object.

I want to do something like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

How do I do this?

I read the FAQ on the Atlassian website, but did not find this implementation. I don't know if it is possible to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a custom field to me. The buttons and text area come from the Velocity template file for the view and edit actions on a field. You'll also need to decide what you want to store in the backend database. My O'Reilly book "Practical JIRA Plugins" has more detail on this, or work through the example at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/How+to+create+a+new+Custom+Field+Type